# How do I evaluate this special type of integral

Tags: integration, functions

Does the following function can be simplified or solved?

$$R(i) = \int_{y\in S} {\frac{{w(y) g(y,i)_{}^\sigma }}{{\int_{x\in S} {h(x)g(x,y)_{}^\sigma f(x,y)_{}^\sigma dx} }}dy} $$

where S is a compact subset of a two-dimensional surface which has positive Lebesgue measure. $w(y)$ and $h(x)$ are weights, $w(y):S\rightarrow (0,1)$ and $h(x):S\rightarrow (0,1)$. $g(x,y)$ is a function which measure the distance between points x and y,$g(x,y):S \times S \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_+$, $g(y,x)=g(x,y)$. f(x,y) =a(x)/a(y),where a(x) is treat as a random variable which draws independently from Frechet distribution . $\sigma $ is a constant.

Thank you very much!

Comment: The denominator seems to be independent of $y$, so you can split the expression into a fraction of two separate integrals. I guess that's the only simplification I can do.

Comment: Thank you. Could you help me to solve it again  if the denominator dependents on y ?

Comment: Without any additional information, I don't see anything that can be done to this expression...

Comment: S is a euclidean space , $g(x,y)$ is a function which measure the distance between point x and y, f(x,y) =a(x)/a(y), where a(x) is random variable which draw from frechet distribution .